# let eclipse have access to root files and folders

Tags: linux, eclipse, apache, root

I'd basically like to enable Eclipse to set up a workspace in the document root of my apache server, i.e. `/var/www`

Right now, I'm using a terminal `sudo` to copy everything from local Eclipse workspace to `/var/www` in order to load the files on the localhost.

I could point document root to `home/user/eclipse/workspace` but there are other files in `/var/www` that I'd like to keep.

How would I be able to let Eclipse setup a workspace in the path `/var/www` which is normally restricted to only super users?

Thanks.